# Access Denied to Group Policy Objects

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

So I've been trying to add a group policy to our servers for the last day or so.

After installing the GPMC and creating an new account with every group membership in the company when I right click on any group policy folder and click New I get a group policy message that says Access is denied.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: My first suggestion is don't go messing with the SYSVOL folder.

Comment: Yeeeesh. By the power of Greyskull, why!?

Comment: our last IT guy was ...special, he created a sysvol folder within the sysvol folder and that folder is shared. Problem? should I unshare that folder?

Comment: So you have a Windows\sysvol\sysvol\sysvol folder that's shared? If you're referring to there being a sysvol folder shared in the Windows\sysvol folder then that's as it should be. You can verify the sysvol and netlogon shares by following this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816833(WS.10).aspx.

Comment: yeah but gpmc cant see that folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally see these errors when you have DFS replication issues on your domain controllers.

The first step would be to check your event logs (heck, that should *always* be your first stem) for FRS, and KCC error events.

Additionally I would run the `dcdiag` and `netdiag` tools on each DC in your environment to verify that everything is ok with your AD infrastructure.

OK so **EDIT**

**AFTER** you get your replication and any other issues worked out (clean Error logs, `dcdiag` and `netdiag` report no error. *THEN* you are going to need to go through and clean up the SYSVOL based on:

> our last IT guy was ...special, he created a sysvol folder within the sysvol folder and that folder is shared. Problem? should I unshare that folder?

Get your replication issues sorted. Then you need to move that manual sysvol folder out of there and if it is sharing needed components, you need to recreate the share using a real file server.

Comment: Here's what failed with DCDiag, I'm not sure what exactly I'm looking at:
     Starting test: frsevent
        Error 5 opening FRS eventlog :File Replication Service:
Access is denied.
 failed test frsevent
     Starting test: kccevent
        Error 5 opening FRS eventlog :Directory Service:
Access is denied.
        Failed to enumerate event log records, error Access is denied. failed test kccevent
     Starting test: systemlog
        Error 5 opening FRS eventlog System:
Access is denied.
        Failed to enumerate event log records, error Access is denied. failed test systemlog